# Are languages regular if their concatenation is regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

Let $A, B \subset \Sigma^*$ be languages.

If the concatenation product $AB$ is regular, are $A$ and $B$ necessarily regular?

I'm inclined to think this is true since the regular language $AB$ has a regular expression and then somehow the regular expression must be comprised of two parts giving regular expression for $A$ and $B$ but don't see how to prove this rigorously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not necessarily true. Let $\Sigma = \{0, 1\}$, $A = \{0^n1^n \mid n \ge 0\}$, $B = \Sigma^*$. Then $AB = \Sigma^*$, which is regular. But $A$ is not regular.

This shows that one cannot necessarily split the regular expression of $AB$ into one for $A$ and another for $B$.

If you want a counterexample in which both $A$ and $B$ are not regular, let
\begin{align}
A &= \{w \in \Sigma^* \mid \#_0(w) \ge \#_1(w)\},\\
B &= \{w \in \Sigma^* \mid \#_0(w) \le \#_1(w)\},
\end{align}
where $\#_0(w)$ is the number of occurrences of $0$ in $w$. Then $AB = \Sigma^*$.

Comment: Ok, of course... $A$ doesn't affect the concatenation at all, thanks. A follow up question: is there a counter example where both $A$ and $B$ are non-regular?

Comment: @ploosu2 Added a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

This is not even true on a one-letter alphabet and even if you impose $A = B$. Take for instance
$$
  A = \{a^n \mid \text{$n$ is odd}\} \cup \{a^{1+p} \mid \text{$p$ is prime}\} \cup \{a^0\} 
$$
This language is not regular since $A \cap (a^2)^+ = \{a^{1+p} \mid \text{$p$ is an odd prime}\}$ is a nonregular language. However $AA = a^*$.