# Is the language "substrings of an even-lengthed regular language" also regular?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language

I want to prove that for a regular language $L$ where $\forall w \in L$ the length of $w$ is even, the language containing the first halves of the words of $L$ and the language containing the second halves are both regular.

That is, for the language containing only `aabbab`, the language containing `aab` is regular (as is the one containing `bab`).

I know that concatenation of two regular languages yields a regular language, and that [the reverse is not always true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649335/are-languages-regular-if-their-concatenation-is-regular). But with this restriction on length, I feel unequipped to answer this question for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any language $L$, let $L_{\frac12-}$ be the set of first halves of the words in $L$ and $L_{-\frac12}$ be the set of second halves of the words in $L$. Also let $L^R$ be the set of reversals of words in $L$.

If $L$ is regular then so is $L^R$. Since $L_{-\frac12} = ((L^R)_{\frac12-})^R$ it is sufficient to show that if $L$ is regular then so is $L_{\frac12-}$.

Let $M = (Q,\Sigma,\delta,q_0,F)$ be a DFA such that $L(M) = L$.

Construct a DFA $N$ as follows:

1. The set of states of $N$ is $Q \times P(Q)$ where $P(Q)$ is the power set of $Q$.
2. The start state of $N$ is $(q_0,F)$.
3. The set of accept states of $N$ is $\{(q,S) \in Q \times P(Q) \mid q \in S\}.$
4. Define a function $\gamma : P(Q) \to P(Q)$ by $$\gamma(S) = \{q \in Q \mid {\rm there\ exists\ }  a \in \Sigma {\rm\ such\ that\ } \delta(q,a) \in S\}.$$
   The transition function $\bar\delta$ of $N$ is defined by $\bar\delta((q,S),a) = (\delta(q,a), \gamma(S)).$

Then $L(N) = L_{\frac12-}$.

**Proof**

Suppose $(q_0,S_0),\ldots,(q_n,S_n)$ is the path taken by $N$ on input $w = w_1\cdots w_n$, and $(q_n,S_n)$ is an accept state. Then $q_0,\ldots,q_n$ is the path taken by $M$ on input $w$ and $q_n \in S_n$.

From the definition of $\bar\delta$, there exist $q_{n+1}, \ldots q_{2n} \in Q$ and $v_1,\ldots,v_n \in \Sigma$ such that $q_{n+i} = \delta(q_{n+i-1}, v_i) \in S_{n-i}$, so $q_0,\ldots,q_n,q_{n+1},\ldots q_{2n}$ is the path taken by $M$ on input $w_1\cdots w_nv_1 \cdots v_n$. Also $q_{2n} \in S_0 = F$ so $w$ is the first half of a word accepted by $M$.

Conversely suppose $wv \in L(M)$ and $|w|=|v|=n$. Let $q_0,\ldots,q_{2n}$ be the path taken by $M$ on input $wv$, and let $(q_0,S_0), \ldots, (q_n,S_n)$ be the path taken by $N$ on input $w$. Then $q_{2n} \in F = S_0$ and so it follows by induction on $i$ that $q_{2n-i} \in S_i$ for $0 \leq i \leq n$. In particular, $q_n \in S_n$ so $N$ accpets $w$.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this does hold for non-palindromic strings (i.e. strings without mirrored halves)... Can you confirm? I apologize for the misleading example, I've changed it to a non-palindrome.

Comment: @j6m8 Nothing I wrote has anything to do with palindromic strings. My best guess is that you are asking about $L_{-\frac12} = ((L^R)_{\frac12-})^R$. This is true because for any word $w$ of even length, the reversal of the first half of the reversal of $w$ is the second half of $w$.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the language $M$ of even-lengthed strings over a particular alphabet is regular. And the intersection of two regular languages is regular. So the language $L \cap M$ of even-lengthed substrings of the language $L$ is regular.

Comment: I think I follow you — though I'm not sure how the intersection pertains to the concatenation..?

Comment: I don't think this addresses the question - the set of even-length substrings is regular, but the question wants to know whether the language defined to be the first half of strings of a regular language is regular.

Comment: @j6m8, I think he's answering the question in the title rather than the question in the body. Maybe you should edit the title to something like "*Is the language of 50%-prefixes of words in a regular language also regular?*"